# Where is the documentation of the Unicode characters, e.g. "»" , for Raku?

Tags: operators, raku

Raku uses Unicode chars like "`»`". Its hard to search for information on these chars as they don't seem to be searchable in Google and I don't really know their names. For example, something like the "`»`" in:

```
$/.make: $<pair>».made
```

Is there a descriptive list of *all* special Unicode chars used in Raku?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think [Unicode versus ASCII symbols section in Raku docs](https://docs.raku.org/language/unicode_ascii) is what you're looking for.

Please note that you *can* search for `»` in the search box on the [Raku documentation web site](https://docs.raku.org). It will give you an extensive pulldown on where `»` can occur in Raku.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google doc to draw your character:

Insert -> Special characters, Draw a symbol here